# gprof command is not creating proper out.txt

Tags: c, macos, bash, unix, gprof

First of all I'm running MacOSX 10.7.1. I've installed all properly, Xcode 4 and all the libraries, to work with C lenguage.

I'm having troubles running gprof command in shell. I'll explain step by step what I'm doing and the output I'm receiving.

Step 1:

```
~ roger$ cd Path/to/my/workspace
~ roger$ ls
```

Output (Step 1):

```
queue.c         queue.h         testqueue.c
```

Step 2:

```
~ roger$ gcc -c -g -pg queue.c
~ roger$ ls
```

Output (Step 2):

```
queue.c         queue.h         queue.o         testqueue.c
```

Step 3:

```
~ roger$ gcc -o testqueue -g -pg queue.o testqueue.c
~ roger$ ls
```

Output (Step 3):

```
queue.c         queue.h         queue.o         testqueue       testqueue.c
```

Step 4:

```
~ roger$ ./testqueue
~ roger$ ls
```

Output (Step 4):

```
enqueue element 16807
head=0,tail=1
enqueue element 282475249
head=0,tail=2
enqueue element 1622650073
head=0,tail=3
enqueue element 984943658
head=0,tail=4
enqueue element 1144108930
head=0,tail=5
enqueue element 470211272
head=0,tail=6
enqueue element 101027544
head=0,tail=7
enqueue element 1457850878
head=0,tail=8
enqueue element 1458777923
head=0,tail=9
enqueue element 2007237709
head=0,tail=10
queue is full
dequeue element 16807
dequeue element 282475249
dequeue element 1622650073
dequeue element 984943658
dequeue element 1144108930
dequeue element 470211272
dequeue element 101027544
dequeue element 1457850878
dequeue element 1458777923
dequeue element 2007237709
queue is empty

gmon.out        queue.h         testqueue
queue.c         queue.o         testqueue.c
```

Step 5:

```
~ roger$ gprof -b testqueue gmon.out > out.txt
~ roger$ nano out.txt
```

Output (Step 5):

```
  GNU nano 2.0.6               File: out.txt


granularity: each sample hit covers 4 byte(s) no time propagated
called/total       parents
index  %time    self descendents  called+self    name           index
called/total       children

^L

granularity: each sample hit covers 4 byte(s) no time accumulated

%   cumulative   self              self     total
time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name

^L

Index by function name
```

Finally. The output file should show something like this:

```
    %   cumulative   self              self     total
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name
 33.34      0.02     0.02     7208     0.00     0.00  open
 16.67      0.03     0.01      244     0.04     0.12  offtime
 16.67      0.04     0.01        8     1.25     1.25  memccpy
 16.67      0.05     0.01        7     1.43     1.43  write
 16.67      0.06     0.01                             mcount
  0.00      0.06     0.00      236     0.00     0.00  tzset
  0.00      0.06     0.00      192     0.00     0.00  tolower
  0.00      0.06     0.00       47     0.00     0.00  strlen
  0.00      0.06     0.00       45     0.00     0.00  strchr
  0.00      0.06     0.00        1     0.00    50.00  main
  0.00      0.06     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  memcpy
  0.00      0.06     0.00        1     0.00    10.11  print
  0.00      0.06     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  profil
  0.00      0.06     0.00        1     0.00    50.00  report
...
```

And it shows blank field.

I searched here and I found nothing helpfully at all. I google it but the same thing.

I would be very grateful If anyone could help me please.

Comment: You can do [better than gprof](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343).

Answer (score 10):

gprof does not work on OS X. The system call it needs was removed several versions ago. It's not clear why the utility still ships. The alternatives are to use dtrace and/or sample.

Answer (score 1):

no need to give gmon.out in the last line, give gprof -b testqueue > out.txt 
see http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_80.html for further reference