# (Visual) Profiling with Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, plugins, profiling, eclipse-cdt

Is there a established standard plugin/ method for visual profiling with Eclipse CDT? By visual I mean not invoking my programs manually and appealing visual output of the profiling results with gauges etc. like in similar Tools (like e.g. Netbeans's Java Profiler).

[image: Visual profiling in Netbeans]

Comment: Interesting that DDMS plugin for development for android does it well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some research, the most common CDT profilers are **GProf** and **valgrind**.

A good tutorial for GProf can be found [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/GProf/User_Guide).

As I'm using MacOSX, [GProf is not usable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616890/gprof-command-is-not-creating-proper-out-txt), because it bases on system calls that seem to have vanished from MacOSX some versions ago. Therefore I recommend valgrind (in combination with Massif) - it works like a charm on my apple and fulfills all my needs (heap usage graph, see below). Both softwares can be found [here](http://eclipse.org/linuxtools/).

EDIT: massif output is better viewed with (guess what) the [massif viewer](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=122409) by Milian Wolff (native on KDE, ports for MacOSX are available). Just feed in the massif output (`valgrind --tool=massif {appname}`).

[image: Massif]